# IE keeps showing the Windows Security asking for username & password and not allowing me to connect

Tags: internet, internet-explorer, proxy

Lately in my university, they set a Username and password for every student (via proxy) to connect to the internet, every thing works just fine with Google Chrome or Mozilla's firefox , when open the browser for the first time it asks for the information I enter it , and it works just fine, when it comes to IE 10: I open it I enter a web site and than this windows appears normally just like with Chrome and Firefox.

the problem s that when it comes to IE (10 in my case), this window doesn't accept the entered data even if they are correct and keeps popping up and doesn't let me conncet using IE, I could just use Chrome or Firefox , but I'm using Windows 8 and I want to benefit from the metro experience, I tried this on Windows 7 too and I had the same problem, I found many threads and discussions about this subject in lots of websites but still can't get a sloution to this, I'll apreciate if you help me out guys .
Thanks

Comment: Could IE10 be trying to use your local computer's domain?